# vb net Click a tabbutton on a webpage

Tags: .net, vb.net, web

Completely new to this, I am unable to get my code to click and activate a tabbutton on a webpage, the part of the website I am trying to activate is

class="tabButton EngagementsHistoryTable"

"Web History"

```
<ul class="tabs_manager_buttons_container lpview_tabs_manager_buttons_container">
   <li class="lpview_underLine underLine" style="left: 0px; width: 132px; 
   display: block;"></li>
 <li class="tabButton VisitorListTable first active">
    <span class="lpview_tabButton tabButtonText" title="Web Visitors" 
     tooltip-align="left" tooltip-delay="1500" tooltip-text="Web Visitors">Web 
     Visitors</span></li>
 <li class="tabButton EngagementsHistoryTable">
    <span class="lpview_tabButton tabButtonText" title="Web History" tooltip- 
     align="left" tooltip-delay="1500" tooltip-text="Web History">Web 
     History</span> 
 </li>
<li class="tabButton AgentListTable"><span class="lpview_tabButton 
     tabButtonText" title="Agents" tooltip-align="left" tooltip-delay="1500" 
     tooltip-text="Agents">Agents</span></li>
</ul>
```

The below code executes the click but nothing happens.

```
 For Each element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("li")
    If element.GetAttribute("className") = "tabButton EngagementsHistoryTable" Then
           element.InvokeMember("click")
    End If
 Next
```

Comment: Tried span class, lpview_tabButton tabButtonText?

Comment: Thanks for that CruleD I have got it working by doing the following

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for that CruleD I have got it working by doing the following

```
    For Each element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span")
        If element.GetAttribute("className") = "lpview_tabButton tabButtonText" Then
            If element.GetAttribute("InnerText") = "Web History" Then
                element.InvokeMember("click")
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Instead of doing it like that I would have done it li>child or li>span. But check which one is more efficient (or you could leave it as it is since it works).

Comment: I'm not sure how you would do it the way you say, can you provide an example please, also next thing I need to do is select date on a filter, I am able to invoke the filter which has 2 calenders a from date and a to date.

Comment: Like you did originally then select span of it or child of it. element<version>.invokeclick. You will have to show html of the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

when invoke calender by similar method

```
      For Each element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span")
            If element.GetAttribute("className") = "filterButton lpview_filterButton EngagementsHistoryTableViewController_filterId6 filter_on" Then
                element.InvokeMember("click")
            End If
      Next
```

From Cal

```
<td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end  ui-datepicker-current-day" data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="5" data-year="2018"><a class="ui- 
     state-default ui-state-active ui-state-hover" href="#">24</a></td>
```

To Cal

```
 <td class=" ui-datepicker-days-cell-over  ui-datepicker-current-day ui-datepicker today" data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="6" data-year="2018"><a 
       class="ui-state-default ui-state-highlight ui-state-active" href="#">4</a></td>
```

Comment: If by select you meant input date of your choosing that would be element.innertext = your text, also, edit the op with new question instead of posting "answers" P: